Is license attribution required for server-hosted (not distributed) use
Am I required to show license and attribution for libraries I don't distribute but use on the web server? Whether to produce the web pages I serve or to access data sources, etc.
To phrase it another way; is it about what I distribute, or what I use to produce the software people are using?

What is the license of the software you're interested in?

This will depend on the licence.
If the licence is conditioned on an obligation, you need to comply with that obligation in order to benefit from the licence.
The obligation may be to show attribution and a copy of the licence upon redistribution of the libraries.
Or, the obligation may be to show attribution and a copy of the licence within any product resulting from the use of the libraries.
There are also licences with no reciprocal obligations.

Splitting hairs here: is the license "included" if it's on the server with the server-side code (neither of which are accessible to the end user of the collective software) or does the website need to provide a way to see the attribution? If it helps, we could ue the MIT license (Expat) as an example.

@BernhardHofmann In my experience, it's not uncommon to require that they display attribution, but displaying the license is probably rare.

@BernhardHofmann A software license dictates what obligations you have to fulfil for you to be allowed to use the software, even on a server, and enjoy other rights under the license. They don't (directly) impose any obligations or rights on your users. Your obligations are entirely dependent on the license. Some licenses obligate you to distribute the license to your users if they interact with the software over a network (notably the GNU Affero General Public License does). Many licenses impose no such obligation (for example MIT or plain GPL).

It depends on the license. Licenses can cover usage, not just distribution.
One example of a license that covers usage is the license for Adobe products. When you buy a 6 seat license only 6 people may use the product at any one time. Windows servers used to have a number of user license. For example if you buy the 100 user license your website cannot legally serve more than 100 simultaneous sessions. This is obviously silly and caused the market to strongly shift to Linux so they stopped it. Today Windows servers have a number of core license. If you've only paid for a quad-core license the OS will only utilise four of your CPU cores.
While GPL mostly concerns itself with distribution, distribution is not the only thing a license can permit or restrict.
Illegal distribution thus falls under two relevant laws: copyright law and contract law (since a license is a contract). Illegal use falls under contract law - you are considered to have broken your licensing agreement with the manufacturer.

Another example is the various non-commercial creative commons licenses. Even if you don't distribute the software, the moment you accept money for the services rendered by the softwar you have broken the license agreement. That's why I prefer simple open source licenses like GPL, MIT or BSD.
